# Axios get in url works but with second parameter as object it doesn't

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, axios

I'm trying to send GET request as second parameter but it doesn't work while it does as url.

This works, $_GET['naam'] returns test:

```
export function saveScore(naam, score) {
  return function (dispatch) { 
    axios.get('http://****.nl/****/gebruikerOpslaan.php?naam=test')
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: "SAVE_SCORE_SUCCESS", payload: response.data})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "SAVE_SCORE_FAILURE", payload: err})
      })
  }
};
```

But when I try this, there is nothing in `$_GET` at all:

```
export function saveScore(naam, score) {
  return function (dispatch) { 
    axios.get('http://****.nl/****/gebruikerOpslaan.php',
    {
        password: 'pass',
        naam: naam,
        score: score
    })
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: "SAVE_SCORE_SUCCESS", payload: response.data})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "SAVE_SCORE_FAILURE", payload: err})
      })
  }
};
```

Why can't I do that? In the docs it clearly says it's possible. With `$_POST` it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 537, accepted):

[`axios.get`](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#axiosgeturl-config) accepts a request config as the second parameter (not query string params).

You can use the `params` config option to set query string params as follows:

```
axios.get('/api', {
  params: {
    foo: 'bar'
  }
});
```

Comment: How do I extract it on the server side?

Comment: @zero_cool you dont need to access params , here wrt example you can access "foo" and it will return "bar"

Comment: Extracting on server side is important point here, I am sure you can use string foo as parameter for your method on server side, but I am not sure how to grab all parameters at once as object inside your server side method. any clue?
I am trying to get this help from this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55602990/reading-axios-get-params-in-asp-net-mvc-controller

Comment: axios.get('api?&foo=bar') || axios.get(api?&${param}=${value})

Answer (score 170):

On client:

```js
axios.get('/api', {
  params: {
    foo: 'bar',
  },
});
```

On server:

```js
function get(req, res, next) {
    
  let param = req.query.foo
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @danikorean, can we write the same client code without using request method alias, i.e. instead of `axios.get` using only `axios({url:"url_goes_here",data:{params:{foo:'bar'}})`

Comment: This server code saved me hours, thank you!  For anyone wondering, stick with 'params' for the .get call, and not 'body' as you may have seen while searching around.  You can re-name it anything on the server side if you wish, but keep params for the client get.

Comment: `axios.get('/api', { params})`  !== `axios.get('/api', params)`

Comment: Why is it that it is `params` on client, but `query` on server?

Comment: This saved me a lot of time, 
Static: axios.get('api?&foo=bar')

||


Dynamic: axios.get(`api?&${param}=${value}`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was working almost for 2 hours to extract the parameter value. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sirhennihau because `params` on client will be attached as `query` to the `url`.

Comment: @AdamOrłowski If the `req.query` on the server is initialized with the `params` from the client side, how does the `req.body` on the server get initialized with from the client side?

Answer (score 0):

For me I was trying to send params using `axios.post`.

When switch both client and server to `axios.get`, `req.query.foo` worked like a charm

Answer (score -1):

This works fine for me. When it is post request nested data object isn't needed but in get requests, in order to send data, you need it.

```
axios.get('/api', {
    data: {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean `{params:{foo:'bar'}}`  as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40953463/4826457)?

Comment: `data` is for `axios.post` using [config object](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig)