# Reading Axios Get params in Asp.Net MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, axios

I am using axios get method and passing params to asp.net mvc controller. I can read individual values. But I am trying to read all values together as one object. I do not have a view model and I am trying to read params as generic object. What will be axios params datatype to use in c# controller as parameter ? I created a seperate method for buildurl and validating each parameter but is there any option to validate all at once?

**This works**

*React Code*

```
export const GetRequestCall = () => {
  const getUrl = 'baseurl';

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get(getUrl, {
      params: {
        param1: 'abc',
        param2: 'efg'
      }
    })
      .then(response => {

      }).catch(error => reject(error));
  });
};
```

C# controller code

```
     //Read parameter as individual strings
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<string> GET(string param1, string param2)
        {
            try
            {  
                var url = BuildUri( param1, param2); 
             }
         }
```

**This did not work**

*Controller code*

```
 //Read parameters as a single object to do some logic. Tried 
    //[FromBody]object, Object, String as parameters datatypes for data
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<string> GET(Array data)
        {               
            try
            {
                var url = BuildUri( param1, param2); 
             }
         }

    private static string BuildUri(string BaseUrl, string param1, string param2)
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(BaseUrl);
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1)) { query["param1"] = param1; }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2)) { query["param2"] = param2; }
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
        var url = uriBuilder.ToString();
        return url;
    }
```

I found option to build query string with name value pairs in C# but not sure on how to pass axios params as name value pair object to c# controller.
Ref: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91783/constructing-a-query-string-using-stringbuilder

Comment: Does axios send the params as query strings? If so, you should be able to bind those to a complex type by using `[FromUri]`. See more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri

Answer (score 3):

There are probably better ways to do it, but one way is to use an **object[]** parameter like this:

```
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public string GET(object[] objects)
        {
            string param1 = objects[0] as string;
            string param2 = objects[1] as string;
            try
            {
                var url = BuildUri(param1, param2);
            }
        }
```

Also you should not use try blocks without catch blocks. I hope this helps