# Vue 3 how to send parameters as json to axios get

Tags: json, axios, get, vuejs3, query-string

I have an api which I'm supposed to send a specific id as parameters to, so that it returns data based on the filtered list.
I tried to send it as :

```
await this.$store.dispatch("axiosGet",
      {url: 'folder/api/property-walls'}, {propertyEid: this.id}).then(response => {
    if (response.status === 'error') return
    this.wallList = response.data.data.data
  })
```

but it doesn't make any differences.
[image]
my API recieves sth like this.
can anyone help me out with the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use params in your get requst

this will work!

```
axios.get('/api', {
  params: {
    foo: 'bar'
  }
});
```

from this refrence

[Axios get in url works but with second parameter as object it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947650/axios-get-in-url-works-but-with-second-parameter-as-object-it-doesnt)